# Fire-powered thrusters?

Tags: electricity, space

So recently I have been working on a science project for ideas that could possibly help in space expeditions, and one of my ideas would be a rocket that would be powered by flame, anyone here have an answer?

Comment: Rockets are already currently propelled by "fire" in the form of an explosive chemical reaction

Answer (score 1):

what you describe is exactly how rocket engines work today: a very violent chemical reaction inside a rocket motor causes extremely hot gases (there's your flame!) to fly out of the exit nozzle at tremendous speed. the pressure forces that accelerated the hot gas produce a reaction force on the motor which equals the motor's thrust.